# How to delete match group?

Tags: match

Say I called:

```
matchadd('my_group', 'regex1')
```

and:

```
matchadd('my_group', 'regex2')
```

I know I could `matchdelete()` on id, but how could we delete match of `my_group`?

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "delete the match group"?

Comment: I hope you are not using some generic group name pre-defined by Vim like `ErrorMsg`.  Because in that case you may delete highlightings, that another plugin created and as a user I wouldn't like this

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If we have answer to your question may be could you accept an answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
for m in getmatches()
  if m.group == 'my_group'
    call matchdelete(m.id)
  endif
endfor
```

Comment: It's better to remember the returned ids from `matchadd()`  and use those to clean up. So you don't have to loop over possible many created matches (who knows how many plugins are using that) and this could be potentially a low slower